# For Loop for incoming UDP feed

Tags: python, for-loop, udp

I am wondering if anyone can help me pseudo-code this one out.

Issue:

I have a live feed coming in coming in from a local host, port 3333. That data is feed is being updated with incoming x & y location, tracked object number, motion and acceleration info.

To derive direction, I need to know where the object was previously and then compare it to its current location.

The issue:

What is an easy way to set up a comparison between a current incoming feed and the previous location from the same feed? Is it setting up a function and storing the location by accessing it through a For Loop?

Code:

```
import tuio, math
print "tuio was imported"
tracking = tuio.Tracking()
print "tuio.Tracking variable assigned"
print "loaded profiles:", tracking.profiles.keys()
print "list functions to access tracked objects:", tracking.get_helpers()
print "Waiting for incoming data", str(tracking.host)  + ":" + str(tracking.port)


try:
    while 1:
        tracking.update()
        for cur in tracking.cursors():
            #print cur.xpos, "this is xpos"
            #print cur.ypos, "this is ypos"
            y2, x2 = cur.ypos, cur.xpos
            #print y2, x2, cur.sessionid
            [For Loop, call a function to store the previous locations?]





except KeyboardInterrupt:
    tracking.stop()
```

Once I figure out how to loop on a live feed, the direction part is easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a different way to do this. The issue with the above answers is that the previous variable for the prev.xpos and prev.ypos is that they are being written to the same location in memory. Instead, I separated the values. It seems to work better. Still thanks for the assistance. It really did help!

```
import tuio, math
print "tuio was imported"
tracking = tuio.Tracking()
print "tuio.Tracking variable assigned"
print "loaded profiles:", tracking.profiles.keys()
print "list functions to access tracked objects:", tracking.get_helpers()
print "Waiting for incoming data", str(tracking.host)  + ":" + str(tracking.port)

previous = None
px = 0
cx = 0
py = 0
cy = 0

try:
    while 1:
        tracking.update()
        #print tracking.update(), "this is tracking update"
        for cur in tracking.cursors():
            #print the location of object, current and previous
            #print id(cur), id(previous)
            cx = cur.xpos
            cy = cur.ypos
            if previous:
                if cx != px or cy != py:
                    #uncomment to find space
                    #print "!"*50
                    dx = cx - px
                    dy = cy - py
                    degs = math.atan2(dx, dy)/math.pi*180
                    print degs, "degs"
            previous = cur
            px = cur.xpos
            py = cur.ypos
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    tracking.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, why don't you just create a list of tuples for the old positions and use `in` to check if the new position is in the list. If you need to, you could use a for loop to compare specific values.

For instance (using a variable):

```
prev_vars = []
while True:
    tracking.update()
    x,y = cur.xpos,cur.ypos
    if (x,y) in prev_vars:
        pass # use this if you only want to see if the object has been there
    for pos in prev_vars:
    #Use this if you want to compare each old pos to the new
        do_something_with_each_old_x(pos[0])
        do_something_with_each_old_y(pos[1])
    prev_vars.append((x,y))#add the new pos to the list
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you. This looks solid. As you say, I could use a loop to compare specific values. I'll certainly be heading this way.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the tuio obj from tracking.objects() have attributes for motion vectors (.xmot and .ymot)?

If not, I think you need something like this:

```
# dictionary to hold previous data about tuio objects
# will be keyed by tuio object sessionid
previous = {}

try:
    while 1:
        tracking.update()
        for obj in tracking.objects():
            prev = previous.get(obj.sessionid, None)
            if prev:
                # there was previous data, do your processing here
                # for example:
                dx = obj.xpos - prev.xpos
                dy = obj.ypos - prev.xpos

            # save current data 
            previous[curr.sessionid] = obj
```

Note, you need to periodically purge old data from the dictionary (e.g. objects that haven't been seen in some interval of time)

Comment: It does have that, however, from my testing of it, it can vary wildly for an object in motion. Plus, xmot and ymot are relative to an object in motion. Once it stops, xmot and ymot will stop.

Comment: Also, I like how clean this is. Thank you for the assistance.